# I am trying to animate text in framer motion nextjs

Tags: next.js, next.js13, framer-motion

I am trying to animate text in framer motion nextjs

```
'use client'

import {motion} from 'framer-motion'
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <motion.h1 animate = {{fontSize:200, color: '#ff2994'}}>
        Welcome to the website
      </motion.h1>
    </>
    )
  }
```

The output is not as expected
[Browser Outpur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooHyF.png)

When I refresh the fontsize of the atrext must increase to 200px but its not happening.

Also you can check out the source code in the browser the headding is shwoing up but the screen is blank
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYiTi.png)

Please help
This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "universitywebsite",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-spring/web": "^9.7.3",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.15",
    "eslint": "8.49.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.19",
    "framer-motion": "^10.16.4",
    "next": "13.4.19",
    "postcss": "8.4.29",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.11.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use this;

```js
'use client'

import {motion} from 'framer-motion'
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <motion.h1
        initial={{ fontSize: "0px", color: "#00000" }}
        animate={{ fontSize: "200px", color: "#ff2994" }}
        >
        Welcome to the website
      </motion.h1>
    </>
    )
  }
```

Comment: No its not working the page is blank I followed a lot of tutorials on the internet..... I am using Nextjs 13.4 and I have a app directory with layout.js... please tell me is there anything I need to play with my app directory in order to get my animations work  ?

Comment: You just need to convert your component to `'use client'` as you did before and also you need to set the initial prop for `motion` component, let me create an example on an cloud editor and send it to you.

Comment: Okay, for some reason framer-motion did not accepted `fontSize` value as number. So change it to string value like this `fontSize: "0px"` and in animate to `fontSize: "200px"` and will work.
you can check it here https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-bartik-tpkqxq?file=/src/App.js:158-262  also, and i edited my answer to right and worked code snippet.

Comment: You have done it in reactjs, I have experience in adding animations to reactjs apps and it totally works fine, please try to implement the same in nextjs application it did not work for me.

Comment: Its same i think, but i will do that too

Comment: please try to do it in nextjs its not working in my case idk why

Comment: Worked Fine!. This is link to example; https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/little-wave-2ydtht?file=/app/page.tsx:12,31

Comment: Hi can u confirm is it beacuse you are using typescript ? Beacuse I was not using typescript and I am writng all of my code in page.js

Comment: It is still not working on my PC I created a new Nextjs app with typescript.....dammm Idk what to do

Comment: Okay so I downloaded the project from your sandbox and tried it its working IDK how its working .....lol.. Thanks for the help ! Shahin

Comment: You are welcome :). Check out your packages.json file, and make sure you have installed the correct version of your packages.

Comment: The error is not from typescript. Just check you packages version

Comment: Hi Shahin, The issues is because I have another package installed  "@react-spring/web": "^9.7.3", and this is somehow overlattimg with the framer motion, when I uninstalled react-spring, everything works good now...

Comment: Oh, That is good! 
I am happy that you found the issue. Good luck!